# Defining constants in es6 class for angular 1.5 controller

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants, angularjs-1.5, es6-class

I am struggling to get this to work. I understand that static variables  cannot be declared in a class in ES 6 format. How can one declare constants within a  class and also access it within the class itself

here is what i have . I am trying to access the constructor value for the constants while $onINit. I do see this.constructor.Consts has the right values . However when i try accessing them using this.getActionConsts.A , It is not there.

Any clues ?

Or is there  a better method of defining the constants

```js
class ActionCtrl {

    constructor($scope) {
      this.$scope = $scope;
    }

    static get Consts() {
      return {
        A: '5010',
        B: '5020',
        C: '5030'
      };
    }

    getActionConsts() {
      return this.constructor.Consts;
    }

    $onInit() {
      this.Actions = [{
        'id': this.getActionConsts.A,
        'title': '1'
      }, {
        'id': this.getActionConsts.B,
        'title': '1'
      }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't calling `getActionConts` inside of `$onInit()`. It works when you change `this.getActionConsts.A` to `this.getActionConsts().A`. Also you can use the class name instead of `this.constructor` its a bit cleaner. I used these docs if you want to read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

When I work with constants I just use the `const` declaration and declare my constants outside of the class. Angular has some fancy ways of defining constants as well which I can't recall of the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Kobe . However , when we declare the consts outside the class, is it possible that the constants can interefere with other constants declared outside other classes ?

Comment: If constants interefere it will result in an Error. You shouldn't have more than one class per a file anyways.

Comment: Consider `ActionCtrl.consts = Object.seal({A: '5010',B: '5020',C: '5030'});` after the class declaration, then the getter is `get Consts() { return ActionCtrl.consts;}`. The constants are public, but can't be modified and are kept from becoming global constants.